# How to convert int to two decimals in ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a table showing JSON data. I need to show the value with decimals, how to achieve this? `result.price` represents a price.
`Component` is a multiplier for the price.

My table:

```
  <tbody>
    {this.state.data.map((result) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{result.name}</td>
          <td> {result.price * component} €</td> 
        </tr>
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
```

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with javascript using the `.toFixed` method of the Number object. `(result.price*component).toFixed(2)` will convert it to a string . E.g. `(2 * 10).toFixed(2)` will print `20.00` as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're trying to format money. Maybe you can take a look to the package [react-currrency-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-format) that will make your life a lot easier with these formatting; you can even add the currency sign of your choice.

For your use case it'd be something like:

```
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';

<tbody>
{this.state.data.map((result) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{result.name}</td>
      <td><CurrencyFormat value={result.price * component} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} suffix={'€'} fixedDecimalScale={true} decimalScale={2} /></td> 
    </tr>
  )
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// create a function to convert your number:
const formatMoney = (num: Number) => "R$ " + num.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");


const formatMoney2 = (num: Number) => "$ " + num.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");


// call the function with param
formatMoney(result.price * component)
```

You dont need import react-currency-format